# Can the SharePoint object model setup data retention on an item?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

OOTB settings allow Information Policy on a document library or a content type.  But I need to extent a farm solution to have different expiration polices on each individual document.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can u add little more details on how u r going to deal with each document?? if possible u can add some scenario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elaborate, the request was to allow data retention (1 month, 3 months, 6 months) for items in one document library.  Separate document libraries could have been used, but when it comes to reports, that would have been more unnecessary coding to compensate for separate libraries.  If one document is set to 1 month, it needs to be moved to the recycle bin, but the other items stay based on their retention.  So a single Information Policy at the library level would not work.

Instead of trying to put data retention on the item itself, Information Policies were setup on content types.  A content type for 1 month, one for 3 months and 6 months.  Using the object model, the item ContentTypeId can be assigned to the respected content type.